# How can I make a sub-domain point to a dynamic IP and the rest of the domain as it is hosted on a server with static IP?

Tags: web-hosting, website, ddns

Basically, I have a domain mydomain.com hosted by a certain hosting company on its servers. I have access to the cpanel and can make changes a s per required. However, I want to host a dvr  remote interface on one of its pages. The DVR is in my office which has a dynamic IP address. I first thought of using the numerous free DDNS services available. But then since I already own a domain name I thought of using that one. How do I do it?

Comment: C'mon guys, the question translates to "can I do ddns on my own domain name" which is a totally valid question.

Comment: @MarkHenderson: Thanks Mark! And yeah I will do more research on my questions henceforth so that I don't bother others on the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a dynamic DNS service just for their provided hostname. Say they give you

```
dvr-103.dyndns.com
```

You can create a `CNAME` record in dns to point a hostname at that dyndns.com hostname. It would look something like

```
subdomain IN CNAME dvr-103.dyndns.com.
```

Pretty much in cpanel create a new host of type CNAME and just point it to the the hostname provided by the dynamic DNS service. That way you can always type subdomain.yourdomain.com and hit the dvr since dns will lookup the ip of the dyndns.com host

Comment: I got this. Will try it. But before that I need to figure out something else. I can't connect to my office network from outside the LAN using the DDNS name. As in I reach my router config page when I use the DDNS from within the LAN but from outside I get a timeout. Is it some firewall issue? Do I need to configure my router firewall to allow DDNS or something?

Comment: chances are you need to open ports on your firewall to NAT a public IP to your internal server

Comment: It will show router config page unless port forwarding is used in router settings.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get around using a dynamic DNS service. Just point subdomomain.mydomain.com to whatever.dyndnsprovider.com.